# Setting Plug.Static Headers in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

I'm trying to put the header **Connection: Keep-Alive** in lib/app/endpoint.ex:

```
plug Plug.Static,
  at: "/", from: :app, gzip: true,
  only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt),
  etag_generation: {},
  cache_control_for_etags: "public, max-age=3153600",
  headers: %{"connection" => "keep-alive"}
```

but when I run `curl -I -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" http://localhost:4000`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
server: Cowboy
date: Fri, 24 Feb 2017 11:34:37 GMT
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 5613
set-cookie: _app_key=...; path=/; HttpOnly
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
x-request-id: aafhn9sq18vpajadu1h7709vmb1f4jrg
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
```

It does not return the header: connection: keep-alive

Is that normal or I'm messing something ?

Comment: `Plug.Static` doesn't serve your home page. You should see the header in `http://localhost:4000/robots.txt` (if it exists) and other static files.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Dogbert, but how I make it in the home page too ?

Comment: The simplest would be to write a plug that calls `put_resp_header`, and add that plug to your pipeline in `router.ex`